# Convert istream to FILE*

Tags: c++, iostream, stdio

Is it possible to convert an `istream` like `std::cin` to a `FILE *`? A cross-platform solution would be a plus.


EX: `(FILE *)std::cin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no standard way to obtain a `FILE*` from an IOStreams stream, nor vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

std::cin is usually bound to file descriptor 1 (or in FILE * form, stdin).

You could just use that. Other than that, the only way to do so is either determine the file descriptor (unlikely) or the filename and use `fopen` to get a FP

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way using `FILE*` I would advise you to use `fstream` instead.

```
std::ifstream in("in.txt");
std::cin.rdbuf(in.rdbuf());
```

This way your redirect cin to your input file stream.

Comment: The OP already has an IOStreams stream; presumably they're trying to interoperate with a C API that uses stdio.

Comment: Right, I should have assumed so :/

Answer (score 0):

Though it is possible that your IOStreams implementation may be implemented using a `FILE*`, the standard does not provide any way of you accessing this information. However, it is of my knowledge that libstdc++ has a non-standard extension `__gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf`, which is a wrapper around a `FILE*`. You can use its `file()` method to return a pointer to the file.

Note that this class is non-portable and non-standard. I think you're better off writing your own stream buffer that emulates its behavior.

Comment: @usandfriends [Here you go.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a00069.html)

Comment: That's the _first_ Google result for `__gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf`, @usandfriends. Learn to search.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a GNU userland (just about guaranteed on Linux), take a look at [`fopencookie()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopencookie.3.html). That allows you to adapt any source / sink to a `FILE*`.

The linked man-page contains in-depth guidance on how to write the adaptor.